# I2C Addressable UART Multiplexer

Tags: i2c, uart, multiplexer

I have a number of "smart" LCDs which have their own internal processor and can communicate over UART. Unfortunately I have ran out of GPIOs on my ESP32. I was hoping to find a demultiplexer (if that is the correct term) which can be controlled over I2C. Best case scenario, my ESP32 only needs to connections to this demultiplexer. I2C to talk to the demultiplexer to select a destination, and data, to be sent to selected destination.

I have come across is a solution using SN74LV4052A. Unfortunately SN74LV4052A is an analog component that does not understand I2C.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an I2C GPIO expander to create the control signals to drive a multiplexer such as the xx4052.

There are a few suitable devices from Microchip and NXP. For example MCP23017.

Comment: MCP23017 looks promising, but I cannot figure out whether it has a dedicated "data to expand" pin (as in, an input pin which is supposed to go to the selected output), or it needs input data to be transmitted over I2C?

Comment: The MCP23017 is a GPIO expander. You would write to it with I2C and the output of the MCP23017 would in turn drive the control signals to the actual multiplexer. It would take two chips to do the function you need.